# How do I create multiple (duplicate) records in a single Microsoft Access table from a single form?

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2010, duplicates

I have been creating a main screen for our training organization. From this main screen, I've created a button that launches the form Instructors will use to enter training evaluations. I've had a request to build an additional button that will launch a different form so instructors can put the average scores for each question and say how many attended the class. Once they submit this form, it will need to create as many records as attendees, so that the weight of each day's averages will be fine when running reports.

I can't find a solution to fit my need, but here is the VBA for the button I've tried to use:

DoCmd.RunMacro "DuplicateRecord", Forms!Feedback_Form!Attendees

This doesn't seem to do anything for me. I know it's pretty simple, but I'm new to VBA.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately from your description I can't understand well, especially because I can't see the structure of your tables.
Anyway, let's discuss about how to copy a record from a table to another.
There are many ways to do that (as usual).
I'll show you two
The 1st is a very compact solution for copying records (just one in your case).

The 2nd is a bit more tricky if you are new to vba but gives you much more control on what you're doing.
Personally I prefer the 2nd solution

**1st Solution - Using SQL SELECT INTO instruction**

The SQL transaction is

```
SELECT *
INTO NewTable 
FROM SourceTable WHERE Condition;
```

In this example *Newtable* is the target table name where you want to copy the record.
*SourceTable* is the name of the table from which you want to copy the record
*Condition* is the condition to select the record to copy. If your record has an ID field (named ID, for example) the Condition can be *ID = NumID* where NumID is the ID value of the record to be duplicated.

How do you use this transactions?
You can build a string for SQL statement and then execute it.

```
Private Sub CopyRecord(lngID As Long, strSourceTable As String, strTargetTable As String)
    Dim strSQL as string

    strSQL = "SELECT * INTO " & strTargetTable " FROM " & strSourceTable & " WHERE ID=" & CStr(lngID)
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

End Sub
```

This subroutine can be called from a form where you are on a certain record in this way

```
    Call CopyRecord(Me.ID,"SourceTable", "TargetTable")              ' Copy record

    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmFeedback_Form", ,acNormal,"ID = "+CStr(Me.ID) ' Open 2nd form @ new record
```

**2nd Solution - Using DAO.RECORDSET**
With this solution you can modify the contents of the fields during the copy.
You can also have different names for the 2 different tables. In the 1st case you physically duplicate the record with the same field names.

```
Private CopyRecord(lngID As Long, strSourceTable As String, strTargetTable As String)   
  dim rsSource as DAO.RecordSet
  dim rsTarget as DAO.RecordSet
    
  Set rsSource = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet("SELECT * FROM SourceTable WHERE ID = " & CStr(lngID),dbOpenDynaset) ' Open Source Table

  Set rsTarget = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet("SELECT * FROM SourceTable WHERE ID = " & CStr(lngID),dbOpenDynaset) ' Open Target Table

  if rsSource.EOF Then Exit Sub                 ' Exit if no record is selected  

  rsTarget.AddNew                               ' Append a new record to destination table
  rsTarget!TrgtField1 = rsSource!SrcFields1     ' Copy Source field 1 into target field 1
  rsTarget.TrgtField2 = rsSource!SrcFields2     ' Copy Source field 2 into target field 2
  ...
  rsTarget.Update                               ' Save new record

  rsTarget.Close                                ' Close Recordset
  rsSource.Close                                ' Close Recordset

  Set rsSource = Nothing                        ' Free memory
  Set rsTarget = Nothing                        ' Free memory

End Sub
```

The call of the subroutine is the same as the 1st case.

**PLEASE NOTE THAT I DIDN'T MENTION THE ID FIELD OF THE TARGET RECORDSET.**
This is very important because if you use an ID field (KEY) with *autonumbering* (as usual) you don't have to assign anything to it because it's automatically generated once you insert a new record.

Let me know if this works for you.

Bye:-)

Comment: SELECT INTO will create a new table. INSERT SELECT will add records to existing table.